# SFML - can't get the projectile shooting in the right direction

Tags: c++, sfml

I use this code to make a monster chase after player, this works just fine:

`float angle = atan2(player.y - monster.y, player.x -  monster.x);
 monster.move(cos(angle) * 0.5f,0);
 monster.move(0, sin(angle) * 0.5f);`

I figured i would change it around so that bullet is shot from player to the mouse pointer:

```
float angleShot2 = 0.0f;

...

case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
        {
         projectile.setPosition(player.x,player.y);
         float angleShot = atan2(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y - projectile.y, 
                                 sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x - projectile.x );
         angleShot2 = angleShot;  //so it goes in a straight line
        }

...

 projectile.move(cos(angleShot2) * 1.0f, 0);
 projectile.move(0, sin(angleShot2) * 1.0f);
```

player, monster and bullet are all rectangles

Window res is 1280x900

After setting position of player I use camera in a way that it follows the player

```
sf::View view2(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 1280, 900));
view.setSize(sf::Vector2f(1280, 900)); 
window.setView(view);

...

view.setCenter(player.getPosition());
```

Bullets are not going where the mouse was released and are going in weird directions, maybe you have some tips for my code or a different method of making the bullets . I really can't come up with anything hmm...
I've tried inverting cos for y and sin for x, disabling the camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that sf::Mouse::getPosition returns the position of the curson in window coordinates while all the entities use world coordinates. You can fix this by using the mapPixelToCoords member function of your sf::RenderWindow object:

```
...
case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
{
     projectile.setPosition(player.x,player.y);
     sf::Vector2f mousePosition = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
     float angleShot = atan2(mousePosition.y - projectile.y, 
                             mousePosition.x - projectile.x );
     angleShot2 = angleShot;  
}

...
```